# change color of submenu on hover

Tags: css, hover

i am kind of beginner in CS

but here's my problem i am already mange to add hover for main menu but the problem i want to unlink the hover code from the sub menu " children menu " 
as you can see http://egy-cash.com/beta/wordpress/ .. the hover code that apply to the main menu also apply to the drop-down menu

here 's the complete CSS file
http://pastebin.com/x9jY2qMu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used this css:

```
.omega-nav-menu a:hover
```

that will affect any `<a>` inside your menu.

If insteed you use:

```
.omega-nav-menu > li > a:hover
```

you will target JUST the direct `<a>` children of your `<li>` element so it will work on your menu. try it out.

For future references this article will help you greetly with the basics of css:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048